# Why do compressed spectra produce soft decay products?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

Compressed spectra, as produced by BSM models like the mUED (minimal Universal Extra Dimensional) model and the MSSM (Minimal Super Symmetric Model), are associated with soft decay products. The literature tends to state this as a known fact, and although it does seem intuitive, how would one explain the reasoning for these low-energy final state objects, explicitly?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anna, and welcome to the site. I think your question is a bit too theoretical  for this site,  You could try https://www.physicsoverflow.org/